# Accessing Variable of an Instanced Class

Tags: c++, testing

Firstly, I apologize for the bad title naming sense. I am unsure as to how to phrase it correctly.

My problem is that I have four given classes, which I call `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` for simplicity.

- `D` is a large class containing lots of data.
- `C` is basically a table containing many `D`s.
- `B` is a singleton and provides `A` with an instance of it. `B` has a member, `C* c`.
- `A` contains a method which calls `B` to do something.

I want to test that `D` has the correct information stored in it, passed through to the program via `A`.

Here is a simplified version of my code that illustrates the setup.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class D {

public:

    // Greatly simplified; this class holds much more data in reality.

    std::string info {};

};


class C {

private:

    std::vector<D*> d {};

public:

    D* getD(int dNum) {
        return this->d.at(dNum);
    }

};


class B {

private:

    C* c {};
    D* d {};

    B() {
        this->c = new C();
    }

    ~B() {
        delete this->c;
    }

    B(const B&) = delete;
    B& operator=(const B&) = delete;

public:

    static B* getInstance() {
        static B instance {};  // singleton
        return &instance;
    }

    bool doSomething(const std::string& text) {
        int dNum = std::stoi(text);  // simplified
        try {
            this->d = this->c->getD(dNum);
            this->d->info += text;
            return true;
        } catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
            return false;
        }
    }

};


class A {

public:

    bool someFunction(const std::string& text) {
        return B::getInstance()->doSomething(text);
    }

};
```

My test should somehow look like this.

```
void test() {
    std::string testString {"1"};
    A a {};
    a.someFunction(testString);
    // How can I test that for the 'D' object 'd', that was manipulated by the
    // call to 'someFunction', 'd.info == testString'?
}
```

I have taken a look at stubs and mocks, but I do not understand how to use them in this situation (I have actually never used them).

Once again, sorry if my explanation isn't clear. I am very weak at C++, and thus do not really know how to explain things. As such, even searching for similar questions proved to be impossible, so I apologize if this question has been asked before.

Edit: I do know that I can do this by implementing some getter methods in B to obtain C, but I was hoping for another method.

Comment: Where does `B::doSomething` get the `int dNum` from? Can it be computed from `sampleString`?

Comment: For simplicity, I assumed that C only contains one D, so the int would be 1. Will make some edits to clarify that.

Comment: How does the `C` get into `B`? It would help greatly if you could edit your examples such that they would be valid C++ code.

Comment: I added in the protected constructor for c = new C();. I do hope that they are valid C++ code now, as what I've done is merely removing other functionality and renamed my classes/variables from my program which compiles and runs properly overall. I may have removed a bit too much, though. =/

Comment: Well, that isn't really valid code, but I do get the idea now. Singletons, global / static state and use of `new` are all toxic to unit testing. Unless you add a member function to `B` that allows access to the `C` it contains, I see no way to test this.

Comment: I have edited your question to make the example code compile. Does this still reflect your problem? Note that there is nowhere a `D` object created so I'm not sure what object would get a property set.

Comment: Yes, that is more or less correct in terms of my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You have not shown whether you are allocating memory to the class pointers. In `a->someFunction(testString);`, where does `a` point to? Then, in `class B`, `neededD = c->getD(dNum);` where does `c` point to? Also, you must change the line `requiredD = d->at(dNum);` to `requiredD = d.at(dNum);`. Please provide complete details to understand the problem better.

Comment: For the point on class B, I added in the protected constructor. Also, the line for requiredD = d->at(dNum) is exactly the same as what is utilised in my code (which works fine if the system testing is proof).

Comment: I don't really understand the line on a-> someFunction(testString). What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Foleosy your code snippet does not show what `A* a;` points to. Have you created object of `A` and assigned it's address to pointer `a`?

Comment: I missed out `a = new A();` and `c = new C();`. Sorry.

Comment: This is not an Answer. -1